# regexp_split_to_array, spliiting on '|'

Tags: regex, postgresql

I've got a string, containing name/value pairs,
`eml:='clientName|img_0196.jpg||mime|||size|3195562||serverFileName|upload/548a5b35003bf.img_0196.jpg'`,

that I need to split on '|'.

I want to get {'clientName','img_0196.jpg',,'mime',,,'size',...}.  My code is:

```
    RAISE NOTICE 'eml: %', eml;
    fields := regexp_split_to_array( eml, E'\|' );
    fieldsLen := array_length(fields,1);
    RAISE NOTICE 'fields, array_length(fields): %,%', fields, fieldsLen;
```

I get:

```
NOTICE:  eml: clientName|img_0196.jpg||mime|||size|3195562||serverFileName|upload/548a5b35003bf.img_0196.jpg
NOTICE:  fields, length(fields): {c,l,i,e,n,t,N,a,m,e,|,i,m,g,_,0,1,9,6,.,j,p,g,|,|,m,i,m,e,|,|,|,s,i,z,e,|,3,1,9,5,5,6,2,|,|,s,e,r,v,e,r,F,i,l,e,N,a,m,e,|,u,p,l,o,a,d,/,5,4,8,a,5,b,3,5,0,0,3,b,f,.,i,m,g,_,0,1,9,6,.,j,p,g},94
```

Can someone help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a backslash: `E'\|'` should be `E'\\|'`.