# Regex substring with '|' in pattern

Tags: regex, string, postgresql, escaping

I have a string of name|value pairs:

```
'clientName|img_0196.jpg||mime|||size|3195562||serverFileName|uplo/ad/548a5b35003bf.img_0196.jpg'
```

I'm trying to extract the value of the clientName, i.e. img_0196.jpg, with:

```
clientName := substring(eml from '%clientName.#"[^|]+#"%' for '#');
```

I've tried lots of patterns (different escaping of '|'), but they all yield either NULL or 'clientName'.
Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459194/regexp-split-to-array-spliiting-on

Comment: Curious to know: what was wrong with taking the array's second element, or the second row of the table's list (with `regexp_split_to_table()`).

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, but I want to know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: What's wrong is you're mixing LIKE matching syntax and regexp matching syntax. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html for details, but in short the percentage at the beginning and end of your expression shouldn't be there, and the `#` characters look weird too -- not too sure what you're hoping to do with those.

Answer (score 0):

From my reading of the docs, what you have should work although it doesn't for me either (in 9.3).

I've had many problems with the `for` version of `substring`, I just don't trust the whole mixing of `%` and `_` with the regex engine and the weird `#"` parsing.

Not sure if you're aware, but you can drop the `for` and get pure POSIX regex, `subtring` will return the whole match OR the first capturing paren if there is one. So to get what you want:

```
substring( eml from 'clientName\|([^|]*)')
```

Comment: Strangely, substring(eml from '%/#"[A-z0-9]+#"[^A-z0-9][^/]+' for '#'); works to get the hex code following the '/'.  Maybe it just doesn't like '|' as a character.

Comment: Right, doesn't change my answer. "Works sometimes" is just another way of saying that something is broken :)